# Is a hotel reservation required for subsequent trips on a multi-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, accommodation, multiple-entry, czech-republic

A month ago I got a multiple entry Schengen visa from the embassy of Czech Republic. During my first stay in the Schengen Area I lived in a hotel, but during my next trips I would like to live at my friend's house. Do you think it's possible?

I won't need to go to the embassy anymore, because my visa is still valid, but I will be controlled at an airport and I'm not sure if I need to have a hotel booking or if some private address will be enough for them. Does any of you have experience with that? I'm not sure if Czech have some different rules, but I will appreciate any experience.

Comment: Can you prove you have enough money for your visit and that you will depart the country?

Comment: Yes, I will have plane ticket back to my country and i will have paper from bank about my account.

Answer (score 4):

It is implicit in a multiple-entry visa that subsequent trips will be more or less different from the first trip.  For example, your second trip on this visa could be to another country, or another Czech city.  Nobody is going to take issue with the fact that you've changed the place where you're staying.

A hotel booking is not required *per se;* it is just one way of showing that you will be conducting yourself legitimately while you are in the country.  Specifically, one condition for entry of non-EU/EEA/EFTA citizens is that

> they justify the purpose and conditions of the intended stay, and they have sufficient means of subsistence, both for the duration of the intended stay and for the return to their country of origin or transit to a third country into which they are certain to be admitted, or are in a position to acquire such means lawfully

A hotel booking is one element justifying the "conditions" of your intended stay.  You can just as easily use an invitation from a friend for that purpose.

Caution: In United Kingdom visitor visa applications, at least, applicants visiting someone who rents their home need to show permission from the person's landlord.  On the other hand, in some jurisdictions, this would be absurd because the landlord has no right to prevent a tenant from having guests.

I do not know how the Czech Republic views this issue.  If your friend rents his or her house, you might want to investigate this question in more depth.